# Issue on Usage of FieldInfo class in .NET REFLECTION

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, system.reflection

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()

Dim resources As   
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(_Class))
    Me.SqlSelectCommand1 = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Me.SqlInsertCommand1 = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Me.SqlUpdateCommand1 = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Me.SqlDeleteCommand1 = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Me.SqlDataAdapter1 = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Me.SqlConnection1 = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

.....
.....



Me.SqlInsertCommand1.CommandText = resources.GetString("SqlInsertCommand1.CommandText")
    Me.SqlInsertCommand1.Connection = Me.SqlConnection1
    Me.SqlInsertCommand1.Parameters.AddRange(New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter() {New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@MAIN_FACILITY_USED", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, "MAIN FACILITY USED")
```

How come with the following line I cannot reach this collection of the parameter regarding to sqlinsertcommand but I can reach the sqlinsertcommand and its commandtext itself by the following code:

```
Dim flags As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic
 For Each info As FieldInfo In AssemblyInstance.GetType().GetFields(flags)
  If info.FieldType.FullName = "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand" Then
    cmd = CType(info.GetValue(AssemblyInstance), SqlCommand)
   End If
Next
```

How can I reach that sqlparameter collection via fieldinfo or other related classes in >NET Reflection?
Seems rude but any help or even suggestion means a lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

so "cmd" is an Instance of "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand" ?! - yes it should.
then it has a property "Parameters" which holds your parameters.

Comment: Yes but when I count the number of parameters they are 0!! while it has 25 parameters in the assembly!

Comment: hmm it should. could you provide a detailed view of your code.
to see when your code gets called.

Comment: mo, the thign is that I have a range of parameters. and unfotunately too many to add it one by one. I was wodnering if there is a way to retrieve the whole range of parameters

Comment: ah ok.
you want dynamically map your input to your defined sql parameters?!